# Using Cmake for a simple CUDA program

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I've been recently dealing with come combined C++/CUDA.
I am learning on this simple exmaple:

```
## this is the kernel build file - a CUDA lib emerges from this

option(GPU "Build gpu-lisica" OFF)
# use -DGPU=ON to compile this

if(GPU)

  find_package(CUDA QUIET)

  if(CUDA_FOUND)

    include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    message(STATUS "CUDA detected -- LiSiCa library")
    set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS ON)
    set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION OFF)
    list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-arch=sm_20;-O2;-DVERBOSE")       

    # build static library
    # CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY(lisica_kernel_lib ${KERNELS}  STATIC)

    CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(demo test.cu)

    cuda_add_executable(
    hellocuda
    test.cu)

    message(STATUS "File setup seems ok.")

  else()

    message(STATUS "NO CUDA DETECTED! GPU-based compilation canceled.")

  endif()

endif()
```

And the .cu (this is directly from the nvidia examples site). I intentionally use something that works with bare nvcc (e.g. nvcc test.cu -o test works). My question is, what am I doing wrong with the cuda code to recieve such errors?

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

// Kernel that executes on the CUDA device
__global__ void square_array(float *a, int N)
{
  int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (idx<N) a[idx] = a[idx] * a[idx];
}

// main routine that executes on the host
int main(void)
{
  float *a_h, *a_d;  // Pointer to host & device arrays
  const int N = 10;  // Number of elements in arrays
  size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
  a_h = (float *)malloc(size);        // Allocate array on host
  cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, size);   // Allocate array on device
  // Initialize host array and copy it to CUDA device
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;
  cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // Do calculation on device:
  int block_size = 4;
  int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);
  square_array <<< n_blocks, block_size >>> (a_d, N);
  // Retrieve result from device and store it in host array
  cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // Print results


or (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d %f\n", i, a_h[i]);
  // Cleanup
  free(a_h); cudaFree(a_d);
}
```

when running the makefile, I get the:

```
[ 33%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//./demo_generated_test.cu.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h(190): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(63): error: expected a ";"
```

.....

Style of errors, which I do not understand, as if I try simply nvcc test.cu -o test, it works.

EDIT: make VERBOSE=ON run:

```
Re-run cmake file: Makefile older than: lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir/demo_generated_test.cu.o.depend
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   filesystem
--   system
--   regex
--   iostreams
-- GSL using gsl-config /usr/bin/gsl-config
-- Using GSL from /usr
-- :::OPENMM_INCLUDE_DIR:         /home/user/project/foreign/openmm/include
-- :::OPENMM_LIBRARY:         /home/user/project/foreign/openmm/lib/libOpenMM_static.a
-- :::PROBIS_INCLUDE_DIR:         /home/user/project/foreign/probis/include
-- :::PROBIS_LIBRARY:         /home/user/project/foreign/probis/lib/libProBiS_static.a
-- CUDA detected 
-- File setup seems ok.
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   regex
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/project/debug
cd /home/user/project/debug && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/user/project/debug/CMakeFiles /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
cd /home/user/project/debug && make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 lib/gpu_kernels/all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/project/debug'
make -f lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir/build.make lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/project/debug'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/user/project/debug/CMakeFiles 7
[ 20%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//./demo_generated_test.cu.o
cd /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir && /usr/bin/cmake -E make_directory /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//.
cd /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir && /usr/bin/cmake -D verbose:BOOL=ON -D build_configuration:STRING=Debug -D generated_file:STRING=/home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//./demo_generated_test.cu.o -D generated_cubin_file:STRING=/home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//./demo_generated_test.cu.o.cubin.txt -P /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.cmake
-- Removing /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//./demo_generated_test.cu.o
/usr/bin/cmake -E remove /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//./demo_generated_test.cu.o
-- Generating dependency file: /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.NVCC-depend
/usr/bin/nvcc -M -D__CUDACC__ /home/user/project/lib/gpu_kernels/test.cu -o /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.NVCC-depend -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -Xcompiler ,\"-std=c++11\",\"-DNDEBUG\" -arch=sm_20 -O2 -DVERBOSE -DNVCC -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/home/user/project/foreign/openmm/include -I/home/user/project/foreign/probis/include -I/home/user/project/lib -I/home/user/project/data -I/home/user/project/debug
-- Generating temporary cmake readable file: /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.depend.tmp
/usr/bin/cmake -D input_file:FILEPATH=/home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.NVCC-depend -D output_file:FILEPATH=/home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.depend.tmp -P /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCUDA/make2cmake.cmake
-- Copy if different /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.depend.tmp to /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.depend
/usr/bin/cmake -E copy_if_different /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.depend.tmp /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.depend
-- Removing /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.depend.tmp and /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.NVCC-depend
/usr/bin/cmake -E remove /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.depend.tmp /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//demo_generated_test.cu.o.NVCC-depend
-- Generating /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//./demo_generated_test.cu.o
/usr/bin/nvcc /home/user/project/lib/gpu_kernels/test.cu -dc -o /home/user/project/debug/lib/gpu_kernels/CMakeFiles/demo.dir//./demo_generated_test.cu.o -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -Xcompiler ,\"-std=c++11\",\"-DNDEBUG\" -arch=sm_20 -O2 -DVERBOSE -DNVCC -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/home/user/project/foreign/openmm/include -I/home/user/project/foreign/probis/include -I/home/user/project/lib -I/home/user/project/data -I/home/user/project/debug
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h(190): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(63): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(68): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(76): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(83): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(93): error: expected a "{"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(64): error: function "std::current_exception" returns incomplete type "std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(64): error: expected a "{"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(79): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(81): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(82): error: expected a ";"

...and so on ...
```

It seems like it tries to include some other projects and compile them with nvcc, thus the errors?

ADDITIONAL INFO: gcc version:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: is this on windows or linux?  I normally only expect to see `#include "stdafx.h"` in a windows enviroment, but the cmake output looks like you are compiling on linux.  If this is on windows, your CMake project is configured to use gcc, and using gcc (as the host compiler) is incompatible for compiling CUDA codes on windows.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the choice of C++ standard to use. Please run `make VERBOSE=yes`, and add the line triggering the error to your question. @RobertCrovella: Judging from the console output, it's a Un*x of some sort.

Comment: This is Ubuntu 16 indeed. I will add the additionall log shortly!

Comment: I am sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 is the OS version (I was looking at the wrong machine).

Comment: and you are including stdafx.h ?  What for?

Comment: I am really not, even if I change the example to e.g. https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/easy-introduction-cuda-c-and-c/, the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that my cmake project set whole bunch of CXX flags upper in the build tree, which I needed to unset in order to make it work properly.